# Export simple Key Frame Animation | Export an animation the way I see it in the viewport to fbx (and then to Unity)

Tags: animation, unity

I have an animation I did with key framing a "simple deform" and armature.
I dont want to neither apply the modifiers nor apply the scale because it totally breaks my animation.

I just want to use the animation how it is. Simple as that. I tried to bake it but it some how 'deletes' the animation.

To do anything in Blender is a pain in the B*** due to lack of any logic or intuition and bugs.
I hope someone could help me with this very basic and simple thing to do.

Best regards

Comment: I guess from what you wrote that you must apply the scale and then rig your model to the armature.

Comment: @Yvain thanks for answering. It has nothing to do with the scale. I did an empty project amd just keyframe the default cube with a deform modifier. There is no way to export it.

Comment: How are you animating the cube ? Via deform or armature ?
You can't use the deform in unity only the armature.

Comment: @Yvain Hey thanks for helping. I deform it with Simple Deform Modifier. I dont want to use it in Unity but export so to say the vertices how they are presented in Blender. So to say bake the animation, for every frame say: this vertice goes here, that one there and so on. 
The Simple Deform does that already in Blender. If I cant export that it would be a big draw back (why having keyFraming at all if you cant use it outside of Blender?)

Comment: Why are you not deforming it with armatures ? effect will be the same for a bend if you rig it to say 3 bones and use IK solvers.
If you need to bake it then your refering to keyshapes, and if that is possible then after the bake don't forget to remove your modifier, maybe that is the fix.

Comment: @Yvain thanks for your involvement,but I havent found a fix. Armature is not near the effect I need (to simulate this I would need hundred of bones). 
I will write my own Animator in Unity and Export an fbx for every frame of the animation and manually change the mesh.

Comment: Yes I just checked and it's not possible to apply deform modifier as shape key, it'll yield one that is empty. You must stick to the armature.